# Display sticky div on scroll-up using Intersection Observer

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

I have 2 top bars - Primary and Secondary Nav Bar as shown in below image. When Scrolled Down the secondary bar becomes sticky and the primary hides.

- When I scroll down, the secondary nav bar needs to be sticky and primary should hide.
- Now when I scroll up, both primary and secondary needs to appear.

[Codepen/Source Code Link](https://codepen.io/sharathm89/pen/xxZGYJw)

**Note:** with smooth transitions so that it doesn't like jump

**Something like shown below**

[image]

**React JS Code**

```
const {createRef, useState, useEffect} = React

function Header({ children, sticky=false, className }){
  const [isSticky, setIsSticky] = useState(false)
  const ref = React.createRef()

  // mount 
  useEffect(()=>{
    const cachedRef = ref.current,
          observer = new IntersectionObserver(
            ([e]) => setIsSticky(e.intersectionRatio < 1),
            {threshold: [1]}
          )

    observer.observe(cachedRef)

    // unmount
    return function(){
      observer.unobserve(cachedRef)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <header className={isSticky ? " isSticky" : ""} ref={ref}>
      {children}
    </header>
  )
}

function App(){
  return <React.Fragment>
    <section>
      <h1>Primary Header</h1>
    </section>

    <Header>
      <ul class="menu-items">
        <li>C Language</li>
        <li>C++ Language</li>
        <li>Java</li>
        <li>C# Language</li>
        <li>Python</li>
        <li>PHP</li>
        <li>Javasript</li>
        <li>R Language</li>
      </ul>
    </Header>

      <div class="content" id="container">
        <h3>On Scroll Sticky Header</h3>
        <p>The header will stick to the top when you reach its scroll position.</p>
        <p>Scroll back up to remove the sticky effect.</p>
         <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque
      <div>
   </React.Fragment>
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

**CSS**

```
// spacer
section{ 
  margin:0; 
  height: 100px; 
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

// smart sticky header 
header{
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  transition: .2s ease-out;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.secondary-header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  list-style-type: none;

  > li {
    padding: 0 15px;
  }
}
```